# Spilled water into my desktop tower

Tags: windows-7, desktop, acer-aspire, water-damage

I have a 2011 Acer windows 7 home desktop with monitor (Acer Aspire X3990). The monitor sits up on a desk and the desktop on the floor. There was a cup of water right beside the edge that was beside the desktop (yah i know stupid but I've had it there before, its like this is some karma). i bumped it somehow, it spilt right through the top vent and around. it had to be within a minute that between the spilling and me screaming 'NO!' multiple times (and the little sounds (faintly) like opening up a can of a soft drink coming from inside the desktop) that it shut down by itself. I unplugged everything within 5-10 minutes and turned it upside down and made my fan face it for about two hours. Called acer support and talked to two people, both say wait a day, one says to put it in direct sunlight tomorrow for the whole day and it should work again and one says to make sure its dry and bring it to a technician. Everyone on the internet has agreed that taking components within the computer and placing them in rice is the best option but I don't even know if it opens up, and i don't know how to take apart the components, i will probably mess something up.

Comment: It sounds like you already have advice from several people (including two from the company that made the computer). What good will it do get get even more advice from anonymous people on the Internet?

Comment: @Blackwood - as one of those pieces of advice was utter stupidity, why not try some random interwebians instead?

Comment: "i will probably mess something up." I assume your PC was on at the time, which means no amount of work, will fix your PC.  Your PC's is terminal.  It is not worth the time or money to fix it.

Comment: [What happens when water is spilled in a powered-on PC?](//superuser.com/q/340225)

Comment: Sorry, the opening a soda can sounds means you fried your motherboard.  You will never find the motherboard they used any more.  At minimum you need a new motherboard, possibly RAM and CPU.  If you got any on the video card that is probably dead also.

Answer (score 2):

The minute you wasted shouting 'No' was probably terminal.

Forget rice. Don't do anything except take it to a professional. Whatever you do, do not attempt to plug it back in.

See this answer on [Ask Different - No sound (speakers/jack) + microphone's dead after spilling water](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/219097/85275) for a cautionary tale.

Comment: "The minute you wasted…" – my thought exactly.

Comment: Why is it wrong to plug it back in? its been a few days now, its clearly dry.

Comment: because you don't know what is still shorted or burned out. Just because you think it's dry doesn't mean it is & only distilled water contains no contaminants, which themselves may be corrosive or conductive. Did you actually read the link?